# TypeScript, AngularJS and GoogleMaps API: scope issue?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-scope, google-maps-api-2

I have this MainController which handles some basic GoogleMaps API Javascript. The bit I am stuck with, is `$scope.clock`, which is an AngularJS element somewhere in the main.html page: `<div><h5>{{clock}}</h5></div>`.

It is first initialized inside the `constructor` and updated once the event `bounds_changed` is triggered (bottom of the code).

Now what I don't understand are the two following things:

- Why does `console.log($scope)` show `$scope.clock = 'Bye Bye'` before `$scope.clock` is updated with `'Bye Bye'`? Shouldn't it be `$scope.clock = 'Hi'`?
- Why doesn't the `<div><h5>{{clock}}</h5></div>` element get updated with `'Bye Bye'`, but it still displays the old value `'Hi'` from the initialization?

  ```
  class MainController {

  constructor($http, $scope, $timeout, socket) {
      var $this = this;
      $scope.clock = 'Hi';
      $this.doSomething($this, $scope, 'Hi');
  }

  doSomething = function ($this, $scope, smth) {
      $this.initialiseMap($this, $scope, $timeout);
  };

  initialiseMap = function ($this, $scope, $timeout) {
      // Use AngularJS’s timer service $timeout and put a delay of 100ms before the map’s initialization  
      $timeout(function(){
          // Initialise the Google map
          $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 11
              , center: {
                  lat: -33.8675
                  , lng: 151.2070
              }
          });
          // Initialise the Geocoder
          var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
         // Initialise Searchbox: Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        $scope.input = document.getElementById('pacinput');
        $scope.searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox($scope.input);
        $scope.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push($scope.input);      

        // Searchbox: Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        $scope.map.addListener('bounds_changed', function () {$scope.searchBox.setBounds($scope.map.getBounds());
            console.log($scope);
            $scope.clock = 'Bye Bye';}); // clock does not get updated in the HTML page!
      },100);
  };
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

> $scope.map.addListener('bounds_changed',

A common issue in angular 1.x. You have an event listener *which essentially angular has no idea about* so the callback doesn't take part in the digest cycle.

Fix : add `$scope.$apply();` to your handler

## More

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: many thanks for this Basarat. Now that I see your name it think I've seen a few of your tutorials on YouTube.